# Linking static library with gnu g++: No such file or directory, Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, static-linking

I'm using makefile to compile my simple application. Here it is:

```
CURRDIR = `basename $(PWD)`
MAINAPP = main
SECTION = section
POINT = point
FIGURE = figure
CIRCLE = circle
TRIANGLE = triangle
RECTANGLE = rectangle

MAINSRC = $(MAINAPP).cpp
SECTIONSRC = $(SECTION).cpp
CIRCLESRC = $(CIRCLE).cpp
TRIANGLESRC = $(TRIANGLE).cpp
RECTANGLESRC = $(RECTANGLE).cpp

MAINKOM = $(MAINAPP).o
SECTIONKOM = $(SECTION).o
CIRCLEKOM = $(CIRCLE).o
TRIANGLEKOM = $(TRIANGLE).o
RECTANGLEKOM = $(RECTANGLE).o

SECTIONHEADER = $(SECTION).h
POINTHEADER = $(POINT).h
CIRCLEHEADER = $(CIRCLE).h
TRIANGLEHEADER = $(TRIANGLE).h
RECTANGLEHEADER = $(RECTANGLE).h
FIGUREHEADER = $(FIGURE).h

MAINEXE = $(MAINAPP).x

COMPILER = g++
COMPILERCOPTIONS = -Wall -c

LINKER = $(COMPILER)
LINOP = -Wall
BIBSTAT = libfigures.a

BIBKOM = section.o triangle.o rectangle.o circle.o
AR = ar
AROP = rv 

$(BIBSTAT): $(BIBKOM)
    $(AR) $(AROP) $@ $?

all: $(MAINEXE)

$(SECTIONKOM): $(SECTIONSRC)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERCOPTIONS) $(SECTIONSRC)
$(CIRCLEKOM): $(CIRCLESRC)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERCOPTIONS) $(CIRCLESRC)
$(TRIANGLEKOM): $(TRIANGLESRC)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERCOPTIONS) $(TRIANGLESRC)
$(RECTANGLEKOM): $(RECTANGLESRC)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERCOPTIONS) $(RECTANGLESRC)

$(MAINKOM): $(MAINSRC) $(SECTIONHEADER) $(POINTHEADER) $(CIRCLEHEADER) $(TRIANGLEHEADER) $(RECTANGLEHEADER) $(FIGUREHEADER)
    $(COMPILER) $(COMPILERCOPTIONS) $(MAINSRC)

$(MAINEXE): $(MAINKOM) $(SECTIONKOM) $(CIRCLEKOM) $(TRIANGLEKOM) $(RECTANGLEKOM) $(BIBSTAT)
    $(LINKER) -o $@ $(LINOP) $^ $(MAINEXE) $(MAINKOM) $(SECTIONKOM) $(CIRCLEKOM) $(TRIANGLEKOM) $(RECTANGLEKOM) 

run: $(MAINEXE)
    ./$(MAINEXE) 

clean:
    rm -f a.out *~ *.o *.x

tar: clean
    (cd ..; tar cvzf $(CURRDIR).tar.gz $(CURRDIR); ls -altr)
```

However, it seems that I have a problem with linking static library. This is my output after executing `make all`:

```
$ make all
g++ -Wall -c main.cpp
g++ -Wall -c section.cpp
g++ -Wall -c circle.cpp
g++ -Wall -c triangle.cpp
g++ -Wall -c rectangle.cpp
ar  rv  libfigures.a section.o triangle.o rectangle.o circle.o
ar: creating libfigures.a
a - section.o
a - triangle.o
a - rectangle.o
a - circle.o
g++ -o main.x -Wall main.o section.o circle.o triangle.o rectangle.o libfigures.a main.x main.o section.o circle.o triangle.o rectangle.o 
g++: error: main.x: No such file or directory 1
make: *** [main.x] Error 1
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong with this makefile?

Comment: `g++ -o main.x ... main.x ...` looks strange. main.x depends on main.x, which obviously doesn't exist...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final command is

```
g++ -o main.x -Wall main.o section.o circle.o triangle.o rectangle.o \
       libfigures.a main.x main.o section.o circle.o triangle.o \
       rectangle.o
```

There's too much going on here: you (1) repeat each object twice (2) use both objects and a library built from them (3) use the output file in the list of input files.

It should be

```
g++ -o main.x main.o libfigures.a
```

You probably need to modify the makefile rule like this:

```
$(MAINEXE): $(MAINKOM) $(BIBSTAT)
    $(LINKER) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I somehow could not find it. Now it works! :)